# Identifying particular area of image using offsets

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, ionic4

I want to identify particular area of a image using set of image offsets. I'm attaching a image and offsets here

[image: Highlighted image]

Sample image offsets for the highlighted area

`Offset(63.4, 195.2) Offset(97.7, 195.2) Offset(112.2, 195.2) Offset(121.7, 195.2) Offset(131.2, 195.2) Offset(139.6, 195.2) Offset(148.0, 195.2) Offset(156.4, 195.2) Offset(165.9, 195.2) Offset(174.3, 195.2) Offset(177.7, 195.2) Offset(180.0, 195.2) Offset(182.7, 195.2) Offset(183.8, 195.2) Offset(184.9, 195.2) Offset(186.1, 195.2) Offset(187.2, 195.2) Offset(193.3, 195.2) Offset(202.8, 195.2) Offset(207.4, 195.2) Offset(210.1, 195.2) Offset(214.7, 195.2) Offset(219.6, 195.2) Offset(224.2, 195.2) Offset(232.6, 195.2) Offset(238.6, 195.2) Offset(247.0, 195.2) Offset(255.4, 195.2) Offset(262.3, 195.2) Offset(267.2, 195.2) Offset(269.5, 195.2) Offset(271.8, 195.2) Offset(273.3, 195.2) Offset(274.5, 195.2) Offset(276.7, 195.2) Offset(277.9, 195.2) Offset(280.2, 195.2) Offset(281.7, 195.2) Offset(285.1, 195.2) Offset(287.4, 195.2) Offset(289.7, 195.2) Offset(292.4, 195.2) Offset(293.5, 195.2) Offset(298.1, 195.2) Offset(300.8, 195.2) Offset(301.9, 195.2) Offset(303.0, 195.2) Offset(306.5, 195.2) Offset(309.1, 195.2) Offset(312.6, 195.2) Offset(316.0, 195.2) Offset(319.8, 195.2) Offset(322.1, 195.2) Offset(323.2, 195.2) Offset(324.4, 195.2) Offset(325.5, 195.2) Offset(326.7, 195.2) Offset(328.2, 195.2) Offset(329.3, 195.2) Offset(330.5, 195.2) Offset(331.6, 195.2) Offset(332.7, 195.2) Offset(333.9, 195.2) Offset(335.0, 195.2) Offset(336.6, 195.2) Offset(337.7, 195.2) Offset(338.8, 195.2) Offset(340.0, 195.2) Offset(341.1, 195.2) Offset(342.3, 195.2) Offset(343.4, 195.2) Offset(344.6, 195.2) Offset(347.2, 195.2) Offset(349.5, 195.2) Offset(351.8, 195.2) Offset(352.9, 195.2) Offset(354.1, 195.2) Offset(0.0, 0.0) Offset(28.8, 211.9) Offset(64.6, 211.9) Offset(70.3, 211.9) Offset(76.4, 211.9) Offset(79.8, 211.9) Offset(82.5, 211.9) Offset(87.0, 211.9) Offset(93.1, 211.9) Offset(104.9, 211.9) Offset(113.3, 211.9) Offset(118.3, 211.9) Offset(120.6, 211.9) Offset(121.7, 211.9) Offset(122.8, 211.9) Offset(125.1, 211.9) Offset(128.9, 211.9) Offset(141.9, 211.9) Offset(156.4, 211.9) Offset(173.1, 211.9) Offset(187.2, 211.9) Offset(197.9, 211.9) Offset(215.8, 211.9) Offset(224.2, 211.9) Offset(233.7, 211.9) Offset(234.8, 211.9) Offset(238.6, 211.9) Offset(242.1, 211.9) Offset(243.2, 211.9) Offset(247.0, 211.9) Offset(250.5, 211.9) Offset(260.0, 211.9) Offset(271.8, 211.9) Offset(276.7, 211.9) Offset(280.2, 211.9) Offset(281.7, 211.9) Offset(282.8, 211.9) Offset(284.0, 211.9) Offset(286.3, 211.9) Offset(288.6, 211.9) Offset(289.7, 211.9) Offset(291.2, 211.9) Offset(292.4, 211.9) Offset(294.6, 211.9) Offset(298.1, 211.9) Offset(299.2, 211.9) Offset(301.9, 211.9) Offset(304.2, 211.9) Offset(305.3, 211.9) Offset(307.6, 211.9) Offset(310.3, 211.9) Offset(311.4, 211.9) Offset(312.6, 211.9) Offset(313.7, 211.9) Offset(316.0, 211.9) Offset(319.8, 211.9) Offset(322.1, 211.9)`

I want to add a click event in the highlighted area of image. Is it possible ?.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is achievable easily with [Image Maps](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp).

In an image map, you add your image, define an area on the image with the help of coordinates, and each area can behave as an individual hyperlink.